# Rewriting a dynamic link

Tags: url, url-rewriting, rule

ugly url is /profile.asp?ID=18751&BN=Starbright Property Care

and I would like it be

/starbright_property_care

any know what the rule would be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `/starbright_property_care` to `/profile.asp?ID=18751&BN=Starbright Property Care`, the ID param will be lost. Which is not a very good idea for performance.

If you still want to go this way, use a `.htaccess` with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$            /profile.asp?BN=$1      [L]
```

And in your **PHP**:

```
$bn = ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['BN']));
```